# Is it possible to wrap a core-js polyfill within a feature detection?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, polyfills, core-js

I'm currently using `core-js` to polyfill my project (by setting the `useBuiltIns` property to `"usage"` or `"entry"` at `@babel/preset-env` ) and trying to find a way to wrap a `core-js` polyfill within a feature detection.

I'm expecting something like this:

**IN**

```js
import 'core-js/features/array/includes';
```

**OUT (Original Output)**

```js
var core_js_modules_es_array_includes__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_166__ = __webpack_require__("../node_modules/core-js/modules/es.typed-array.includes.js");
...
```

**OUT (Expected)**

```js
if (Array.prototype.includes == undefined) {
    var core_js_modules_es_array_includes__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_166__ = __webpack_require__("../node_modules/core-js/modules/es.typed-array.includes.js");
    ....
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The polyfill logic likely already does feature detection, why are you trying to do it yourself?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, thanks for your reply. My project will pass code as string to WebDriver, and WebDriver will pass the string to a website to execute it. The problem is that I can't expect what the target website has polyfilled, which leads to " Cannot redefine non-configurable property '__' " problem.